# jquery ajax simple post/get

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

```
function selectTinNumber(object){   
    $.ajax({
        url: '..//include/crud.php',
        data: 'pin=' + object.value,
        cache: false,
        error: function(e){
            alert(e);
        },
        success: function(e){
            // A response to say if it's updated or not
            alert(e);
        }
    });   
}
```

i have this code for ajax i want to use it to select query my database in my crud.php i have a function called `selectAllPin()` , where i use data `pin`. I use `pin` as `if(isset($_GET['pin'])){` my question is why do i always get alert like this `object Object`.. How do i connect my function `selectAllPin()` to this ajax any help is appreciated

Comment: data: 'pin=' + object.value, should also be: data: 'pin': object.value,

Comment: @KoenHoeijmakers i get error on your comment sir

Comment: What are you echoing in your PHP function? Please include your PHP script or, as @sanfor said below, just loop through your object or log it in the console. Also, your URL must be wrong.. `//` should never ever be there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[ajax Get](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)

```
function selectTinNumber(object){   
    $.ajax({
        url: '../include/crud.php?pin=' + object.value,
        cache: false,
        error: function(e){
            alert(e);
        },
        success: function(e){
            // Response here
            alert(e);
        }
    });   
}
```

Comment: i think i understand what i am missing i will try this out sir

Comment: i am still working on it sir i will be back on you on this one this will take a while

Comment: in crud.php just use `echo $_GET['pin']` i assure u get the answer

Comment: i get this i did your code plus echo `Notice: Undefined index: pin in`

Comment: i got it sir...thank you so much it worked..i hope this question will help someone like me

Answer (score 0):

You get *Object object* because the thing you are alerting is object. You would need to read it's appropriate attributes such as `e.result`. If you want to see what all the object contains, you can use this

```
for (var i in e)
{
  alert(i + ": " + e[i]);
}
```

to iterate through all attributes of object *e*.

Comment: now i can see all the error..what did i miss here i want to use the pin variable on my function what i missing here it does not go into the function `selectAllPin()`..what do i need to add so i can make it a simple query?

Comment: Well, then you might want to take a look at what the error status is, which is the second parameter of callback function. Alter the error function declaration as follows: `function(e, status)` and then `alert(status)`. If it is 404, your URL that you try to AJAX into, is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Use console.log to the the content or JSON.stringify, that should help. I think the data can be found with e.data.